# Given a polynomial of degree 5 how to find its maxima or minima

Tags: derivatives

Suppose that $f(x)= x^{5}+3$

$f'(x)=5*x^{4}$

To get maxima/minima the first-order derivative is equated to $0$

$f'(x)=5*x^{4}=0$  => $x=0$

No matter what the degree of $x$, the value of $x=0$

How can I get maximum or minima value?

Can we get maxima or minima for any polynomial by second-order derivation?

Comment: Have you considered the graph of the function? This will help a lot.

Comment: You should study the roots of the derivative and check whether its sign changes from negative to positive or the vice verca or is of same sign

Comment: In this case the function doesn't have any extrema at 0

Comment: can we have a function without extrema other than constant

Comment: @Ss yes there are many functions

Comment: In your example $(0;\;0)$ is an inflexional point with 'horizontal' tangent

Comment: @Aditya if a function has extrema than will double derivative is sufficient to get maxima/minima

Comment: I don't think that you are right but most of the times it works

Comment: @Aditya what if it won't work, Does it implies the function doesn't have maxima/minima

Comment: No then you have do what I said in the previous comment if you want to check local Maxima or minima and the method works all the time

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the perfect examples to show that $f'(x)=0$ does not always imply that $x$ is an extremum.

Look at the graph of your polynomial and you will quickly realise what is happening.

As for the maximum and minimum values of a polynomial with odd degree, remember what happens when $x$ tends to either $+ \infty$ or $- \infty$.

Comment: if I have an interval of values for x, I can get maximum or minimum for that polynomial $f(x)=x^5+3$

Comment: If you are indeed restraining yourself to some interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, you should look at the maximum and minimum of your interval. Again, the easiest way probably is to plot the graph of this polynomial. This should guide your reflexion.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** The polynomial is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$, so it has no extremum.

Comment: I think the op is talking about local extrema not absolute

Comment: Ok I edited my post